# JS Summernote Filling Two Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I have a piece of code that grabs the value from a summernote input area and places it into another element (#intro_one) within an iframe on my page.

```
var intro1 = $('#intro-summernote').code();
previewContent.find('#intro_one').html(intro1);
```

This works fine, however i am also trying to insert the same value within another element.

```
previewContent.find('#intro_one_mobile').html(intro1);
```

This one does not work. I have tested populating the "#intro_one_mobile" with dummy data and it inserts correctly, when trying to reuse (insert) the summercode value into more than 1 element, it doesn't work.

Any input here would be great, thanks

Comment: What does `$('#intro-summernote').code();` return? I can't find any reference to it in their [docs](https://summernote.org/deep-dive/). Are you sure `#intro_one_mobile` exists in the DOM and is visible when you attempt to add the content to it?

Comment: It returns the value of a summernote input field (wysiwig text box). As  i said, i tried adding dummy data to the #intro_one_mobile through the html() function and it worked, so it is visible in the DOM,